# AngularJS Multiple directives asking for ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

Here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hr121r18/3/) of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I'm trying to build a US phone number input where the view displays as (333) 555-1212, but the model binds to the numeric integer 3335551212.

My intention is to add custom validators to `NgModelController` which is why I have `require: ng-model`; there are simpler solutions without the isolate scope and `NgModelController`, but I need both.

You'll see an immediate error in the console: `Error: Multiple directives [ngModel, ngModel] asking for 'ngModel' controller on: <input ng-model="user.mobile numeric" name="telephone" type="tel">` -- thought I was using an isolate scope here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for looking @mimir137 but I appear to have solved it:

http://jsfiddle.net/hr121r18/8/

The directive was using `replace: true`, which ends up with this structure:

```
<form ng-controller="FooCtrl" class="ng-scope">
    <p>Enter US phone number</p>
    <input ng-model="user.mobile numeric" name="telephone" type="tel">
</form>
```

Both the template and the markup called for `ng-model` which led to the symptomatic error in the problem description.  Once I removed that, it leads to this markup (note the wrapper element `phone-number`):

```
<form ng-controller="FooCtrl" class="ng-valid ng-scope ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" abineguid="BC0D9644F7434BBF80094FF6ABDF4418">
    <p>Enter US phone number</p>
    <phone-number ng-model="user.mobile" class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">
       <input ng-model="numeric" name="telephone" type="tel" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched">
    </phone-number>
</form>
```

But removing this required changes to `$render`; the `elem` passed into the link function is now `phone-number` and so you need to dig to grab the `input` inside it and set the value on that:

```
ngModel.$render = function () {
  elem.find('input').val($filter('phonenumber')(ngModel.$viewValue));
};
```

There were a few other issues.  `$render()` also needed to be called from the watcher.

Final:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

// i want to bind user.mobile to the numeric version of the number, e.g. 3335551212, but 
// display it in a formatted version of a us phone number (333) 555-1212
// i am trying to make the directive's scope.numeric to have two-way binding with the controller's
// $scope.user.mobile (using isolate scope, etc.).
app.controller('FooCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
        mobile: 3335551212
    };
});

app.directive('phoneNumber', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input ng-model="numeric" name="telephone" type="tel">',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            numeric: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

            // update $viewValue on model change
            scope.$watch('numeric', function () {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.numeric);
                ngModel.$render();
            });

            // $modelValue convert to $viewValue as (999) 999-9999
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                return $filter('phonenumber')(String(modelValue).replace(/[^0-9]+/, ''));
            });

            // $viewValue back to model
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                var n = viewValue;
                if (angular.isString(n)) {
                    n = parseInt(n.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''));
                }
                return n;
            });

            // render $viewValue through filter
            ngModel.$render = function () {
                elem.find('input').val($filter('phonenumber')(ngModel.$viewValue));
            };

        }
    };
}]);

app.filter('phonenumber', function () {
    return function (number) {
        if (!number) {
            return '';
        }
        number = String(number);
        var formattedNumber = number;
        var c = (number[0] === '1') ? '1 ' : '';
        number = number[0] === '1' ? number.slice(1) : number;

        var area = number.substring(0, 3),
            exchange = number.substring(3, 6),
            subscriber = number.substring(6, 10);

        if (exchange) {
            formattedNumber = (c + '(' + area + ') ' + exchange);
        }
        if (subscriber) {
            formattedNumber += ('-' + subscriber);
        }
        return formattedNumber;
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<form ng-controller="FooCtrl">
    <p>Enter US phone number</p>
    <phone-number ng-model='user.mobile'></phone-number>
</form>
```

Comment: it's not obvious what you changed in the code, but glad you found a solution.

Comment: @Claies compare begin fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hr121r18/3/ (which was a total hackathon) with end fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hr121r18/8/

Comment: I can compare them if I really was interested in the difference, but a good answer doesn't rely upon links to fiddles or whatnot that may not exist in the future.  Anyone having a similar issue and finding your question is looking for something to explain what's wrong, not code they have to compare and contrast.

Answer (score 0):

I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x0srby22/3/) that gets rid of most of your errors coming up in the console. Hopefully this will at least be able to put you on the right track.

I changed the template so that you can see that the filter is actually working.
It now has the typical `{{ngModel | FilterName}}` in plain text underneath the textbox.
The only real issue is displaying it in the textbox. I'm sure you will have no problem with that. I will check in the morning just in case you still have questions regarding this.

Edit: Alright it appears you have solved it already. Great job!

Comment: I have a custom filter - not sure if you looked at the fiddle.